# How can you modify a PyTorch DataLoader to process input?

Tags: pytorch, rasterio, pytorch-dataloader

All of the input data that I want to train my model on is in 8-band, 16-bit tif files. However, PIL can only handle 3-band 8-bit files. I found that the following code allows me to convert my files into a PIL Image object, and I was wondering if there is a way to modify the DataLoader to apply this or a similar method.

```
filename = "out_crops/0/0_crop_20220423_144035_19_2430.tiff"
src = rasterio.open(filename)
image = (src.read([6,4,2]) >> 8).astype('uint8')
input_image = Image.fromarray(reshape_as_image(image))
```

I know that I could iterate over every file, convert it to the needed bands/bits, and write those to a new folder, but I'd prefer to keep all input in its original format for the future. Thank you in advance for the help